# Contador adicionando um valor a mais no vetor com ponteiro

Tags: c, array

Eu estou tentando terminar um exercício que pede 4 idades e o *output* fala quantas das idades inseridas são maiores ou igual a 18 mas o contador adiciona sempre um valor superior a 18 no final e não entendo o porquê.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int vetor[3], *pvetor = &vetor[0],i,cont=0;
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    printf("Introduza a %d idade: ",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&vetor[i]);
}
while(*pvetor != NULL)
{
    if(*pvetor >= 18)
        cont++;
    pvetor++;
}
printf("Das %d idades inseridas, %d sao maiores de idade.",4,cont);
}
```

Comment: Esse código não parece fazer o que está descrito, o erro é no código ou na descrição?

Comment: Enganei-me na descrição o propósito é falar quantas idades são maiores ou igual a 18*

Comment: Não, isto está escrito na descrição. Sem saber qual é o problema, não tem como saber qual é a solução.

Comment: Já corrigi a descrição

Answer (score 3):

Se é para receber 4 idades o *array* deve ter tamanho 4. Pode fazer a contagem já na entrada. Não precisa de ponteiro. Se sabe que é 4 idades não tem porque parametrizar isto. E isto é C e não C++.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int vetor[4], cont=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("Introduza a %da. idade: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &vetor[i]);
        if (vetor[i] >= 18) cont++;
    }
    printf("Das 4 idades inseridas, %d sao maiores de idade.", cont);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/GtIz8g). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/yvveqaxk-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/ArrayLoop.c).

Comment: Mas um array começa do 0 logo colocar 3 deixaria 4 espaços não?

Comment: Não, quando declara tem que dizer o tamanho, não qual é o último elemento.

Comment: Eu percebo que não faça sentido utilizar ponteiros dessa forma mas o objectivo do exercício é o uso de ponteiros para resolver o problema e alterar o tamanho do array não alterou o resultado final no entanto colocar cont-- após terminar o ciclo while funciona mas eu gostaria de saber porque é que o contador está adicionando um valor a mais no final do array, só isso..

Comment: Qualquer exercício que exija fazer algo que não deve é um exercício ruim e furado por definição e está exercitando para o mal. Inclusive de fato isto está no código e tem função zero nele, nem pra causar problema ele tá servindo. O contador não está adicionando nada a mais.

Comment: O OP ao invés de aceitar a sua resposta, preferiu se autodestruir?

Comment: @VictorStafusa aparentemente sim, esse é o estado das coisas hoje em dia, ninguém se compromete, é tudo fugaz